# iphone : Play and pause a song for particular time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my app,

song play through AVAudioPlayer,

now i want to play a song  for particular time than pause for particular time & play again.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `NSTimer` and invoke a method after a given period of time. So, make two methods, pause: and play:, for example

```
- (void)pause:(id)sender {
    [player pause];
}
```

and then invoke this method using a scheduled time after a given time period like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(pause:) userInfo:nil repeats:no
```

so in this case, after 3 seconds, pause will be invoked in 'self'.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `AVPlayer` instead of `AVAudioPlayer` then you can use the method

```
- (id)addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:(CMTime)interval queue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue usingBlock:(void (^)(CMTime time))block
```

Which will call the block at the set interval for as long as the item is playing. The parameter `Time` passed to the block will tell you how long the current item has been playing for.

Therefore all you'd need to do would be to test the `Time` value and if it's a certain length then call `pause` to stop the player. You could then setup a one-time timer to fire after a certain amount of time to recommence playback.